# Android Studio / ¿Por que las vistas de mi recycler view no se adaptan al ancho de la pantalla?

Tags: android, android-studio

Quiero dar un **efecto** para que se note que una vista **se seleccionó** como sucede con **WhatsApp** al seleccionar algún chat del recycler view.

Mi problema **no es** que no puedo colorear las vistas al ser seleccionadas, sino que no encuentro la forma de **estirar la vista** para que ocupe **todo el ancho** de la pantalla para que al tocar una vista, se coloree desde el **principio hasta el fin** y no a medias como se puede ver en la siguiente foto.

**Adjunto foto en la que se puede ver que solo se colorea hasta donde llega el texto**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Adjunto otra foto en la que se puede ver que ni siquiera puedo hacer estirar las vistas agregando elementos ajustados al extremo derecho (El +1 corresponde a un text View diferente al text view que contiene el mensaje de cada persona)**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Adjunto el código XML de las vistas del recycler view**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/linear_chat"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/seleccion_popup_chat"
android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_foto_item_row_recycler_chat"
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_contenido"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_nombre_item_row_chat"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:text="Cristian Domineck"
            android:textColor="#353333"
            android:textSize="17sp" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_mensaje_item_row_chat"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"
                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                android:text="Si, podes venir cualquiera de essos dias"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
                android:textColor="#7C7C7C"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:singleLine="true"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_cantidad_mensajes_item_row_chat"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"
                android:text="+1"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.925"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/txt_mensaje_item_row_chat"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_estado_mensaje_item_row_chat"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:fontFamily="@font/heebo_thin"
                android:text="Recibido a las 20:28"
                android:textColor="#757575"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Adjunto el código JAVA del adaptador del recycler**

```
@Override
public adapter_recycler_chat_favoritos.ViewHolderDatos onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_row_recycler_chat,null,false);

    view.setOnClickListener(this);

    final ViewHolderDatos holder = new ViewHolderDatos(view,this.context);

    holder.linear_chat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {      
            String nombre = array_model_recycler_chat.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getNombre();
            String url_foto = array_model_recycler_chat.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getUrl_img_foto();

            if(contador == 0){
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, chat_individual.class);
                intent.putExtra("nombre",nombre);
                intent.putExtra("url_foto",url_foto);
                context.startActivity(intent);

                contador++;

                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        contador = 0;
                    }
                },500);
            }
        }
    });
return holder;}
```

**Desde ya, muchas gracias por leer**

Answer (score 1):

Prueba esto:

```
LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

o en el archivo xml donde esta tu recyclerView:

```
app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
```

Comment: La primer forma (el código java) ya lo usé. No estoy seguro pero creo que sin eso no funcionaría el recycler. Probé la segunda forma que me diste (xml) y tampoco funcionó. Agradezco igualmente tu respuesta :((

Answer (score 0):

Creo que es un problema del layout básicamente, la imagen circular la tienes fuera del grupo, si te pones la vista de BluePrint verás como los Views están desordenados y algunos unos fuera de otros, jugando un poco con tu layout y definiendo un LinearLayout como horizontal para dar cabida a la imagen y al otro LinearLayout con el grupo de textos entonces queda más organizado, ahora ese LinearLayout si lo indicas con width="match_parent" ocupará todo el ancho de la pantalla y a la vez es el contenedor de todos los elementos, por lo tanto puedes darle un fondo a ese LinearLayout (o lo que desees).

Te dejo el código XML que cree para tu caso y una captura del resultado final (le puse un color de fondo a ese LinearLayout con id "linear_contenido (intenté modificar lo mínimo para que fuera fácil de entender para tu caso y puedas aplicarlo)":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_contenido"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_foto_item_row_recycler_chat"
            android:layout_width="56dp"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_nombre_item_row_chat"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                android:paddingLeft="12dp"
                android:text="Cristian Domineck"
                android:textColor="#353333"
                android:textSize="17sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/constraint_punto"
                    android:layout_width="4dp"
                    android:layout_height="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:background="#006064"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_estado_mensaje_item_row_chat"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/heebo_thin"
                    android:text="Recibido a las 20:28"
                    android:textColor="#757575"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


            </LinearLayout>

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_mensaje_item_row_chat"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
                    android:paddingLeft="12dp"
                    android:text="Si, podes venir cualquiera de essos dias"
                    android:textColor="#727171"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Captura de como queda el resultado (recuerda quitar el color de fondo): 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Un saludo y espero que te sea de utilidad.

Leyendo tu código recuerda que cuando haces el setBackground se lo tienes que hacer al primer LinearLayout con id linear_contenido. Quedando de la siguiente forma:

```
holder.linear_contenido.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
```

Comment: Ramón, muchisimas gracias por la respuesta. Aún asi, no me funcionó. Sigo obteniendo el mismo resultado. Por si aporta algo, estoy trabajando con la API 20

Comment: Que  curioso, a mi me funciona perfectamente. Le puse un onClick y al pulsar se cambia el color a todo el LinearLayout, y puse lo mismo: 
                linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(v.getContext().getResources).getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));

¿Has comprobado bien la organización? Que este todo metido en un LinearLayout y luego cambias el color sobre ese LinearLayout? Si no, lo siguiente que se me ocurre que sea cosa del adaptador.

Comment: Copié y pegué tu código. No se que pasa. Gracias igual :(

Comment: Hombre, más que copiarlo deberías entender el por que para poder adaptarlo a tus necesidades y si te vuelves a enfrentar al mismo problema saber como solucionarlo. Lee el código tranquilo, por lo que vi llevas varios días haciendo una aplicación y preguntando. Date un paseo, una vuelta o un día de descanso, luego retoma el  proyecto y al leerlo seguro que te queda todo más claro. Todos necesitamos un descanso de vez en cuando, por mucho que nos guste estudiar y picar código.

Comment: No hago casi nada sin entender porque no me gusta. Primero lo leí, después lo interpreté y luego lo copié. Amo programar y por suerte no puedo parar de hacerlo. Aún así, por alguna razón que no entiendo el código no me funciona. De nuevo te agradezco por responder y para terminar quiero agregarte una pregunta: Probaste el código? Porque la imágen que me pasas en la cual la vista está en color rosa, es de la vista diseño. Si yo cambio el color en la vista diseño también se aplica a toda la vista. El problema está cuando se ejecuta la aplicación.

Comment: Si claro, el rosa es aposta para ver claramente el LinearLayout con al que quiero hacer referencia. Es un modo de saber a simple vista que está todo dentro del LinearLayout que a veces con el BluePrint no se ve claro cuando pasas una captura.

Answer (score 0):

El problema esta en esta línea de código.
`View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_row_recycler_chat,null,false);`

Se debe cambiar la variable `null` por `parent`.

`View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_row_recycler_chat,parent,false);`